# CSS All Body Content Centered

Tags: css, html

How to center all the HTML elements horizontally and vertically between the `<body> </body>` without updating the elements `left:` and `top:` property when the window gets resised.

Comment: This question is a bit too general: Keep in mind that centering HTML elements does not imply that their *content* again is centered, like text inside a DIV or a DIV inside another DIV etc., as it's the case in most situations.

Answer (score -1):

.center { margin: auto auto 3px 3px; }

By using this in your internal or external CSS file all the text elements will be center aligned and there will be a margin of 3 pixels above and below the division.

Comment: You also need a width declared. Block-level elements have width: 100% by default so just the above won't change anything. Plus the margin shorthand is off. That says "top: auto, right: auto, bottom 3px, left 3px". Update to:

.center {width: 960px; margin: 3px auto;}

Comment: that's wrong: the order in combined CSS rules is top - right - bottom - left, so this would be auto at top and right and 3px bottom and left. Plus this doesn't do anything if there isn't any position parameter.